# SQL Server 2012 Performance issue using FULLTEXT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012 Standard and I have some issue using the `CONTAINS` clause on a query.

My query:

```
select * 
from 
    calles as c 
INNER JOIN 
    colonias as col ON c.ID_Colonia = col.ID_Colonia
where 
    CONTAINS(c.Nombre,@Busqueda) OR CONTAINS(col.Nombre,@Busqueda)
```

If I use only one contains the time of the search is about 200 ms but if I use both it is about 10s (that's a lot of time). I try a workaround to do it using `UNION` like this:

```
select * 
from 
    calles as c 
INNER JOIN 
    colonias as col ON c.ID_Colonia = col.ID_Colonia
where 
    CONTAINS(c.Nombre,@Busqueda) 

UNION 

select * 
from 
    calles as c 
INNER JOIN 
    colonias as col ON c.ID_Colonia = col.ID_Colonia
where 
    CONTAINS(col.Nombre,@Busqueda)
```

And the query time is about 200ms again. But I think that the second code is clumsy. Do I have some error?

Comment: This sounds more like an issue with using `Or` than it is with `Contains`.  Have you looked at the query plans for both of these?

Answer (score 0):

`FULLTEXT` index in SQL Server is a service which is (kinda) external to the RDBMS engine.

It accepts the search string and returns a list of key values from the table (which need then to be joined with the table itself to be sure they're still there).

So in fact you are joining two more tables in your query and apply an `OR` condition to the result of the join.

SQL Server's optimizer is not especially smart when it comes to constructs like this.

Replacing an `OR` condition with a `UNION` is a legitimate and commonly used optimization technique.